# Не могу скомпилировать библиотеку irrlicht под code::block

Tags: c++, irrlicht

Я скачал библиотеку с github. Зашел в irrlicht-1.9\source\Irrlicht открыл готовый проект под code::block и начал собирать но выскочила ошибка.

`C:\libraries\irrlicht-1.9\source\Irrlicht\aesGladman\sha2.cpp|392|error: narrowing conversion of '13096744586834688815ull' from 'long long unsigned int' to 'sha2_64t {aka long long int}' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]|`
Подскажите пожалуйста что делать.